# postgresql provide PSQLException: ERROR: non-integer constant in GROUP BY when I GROUP BY TRUE

Tags: java, postgresql

After we bumped our Postgresql version to 15 it starts throwing an error that `PSQLException: ERROR: non-integer constant in GROUP BY` when my SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
GROUP BY TRUE, column
ORDER BY TRUE, column
```

Is it not allowed anymore to use TRUE in group by/order by? Where can I find info about this?

I expect it to works as on previou verions.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and `TRUE::boolean` ended up being the working solution in this case. I think the issue is one of it being a keyword and the parser having changed?

Comment: @AnyaShenanigans TRUE::boolean helps. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, based on this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Uu1XdII5) it seems to be connected with the PostgreSQL 15 upgrade.

In 14 [works](https://dbfiddle.uk/qZcRuBd0).

Anyway  e.g. `group by true::boolean` help, or better **remove it** at all as it plays no role!

Comment: It helps, 
Thanks a lot!
I can't remove it because we build our columns string dynamically and I need this as a mock